# Желательно ли в yii-2, закрытать доступ к админки с помощью Robots.txt?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Желательно ли в yii-2, закрытьва доступ к админки с помощью Robots.txt?

Так как единственная папка открытая для веб это `web`, в которой храняться стили, index.php , то соответственно не очень понято нужно ли создавать файл Robots.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

robots.txt нужен в корне любого сайта всегда. иначе лог ошибок будет заспамлен обращениями к нему.

Однако следует понимать, что никакой "доступ" этот файл никуда не закрывает.

Доступ к админке следует закрывать с помощью авторизации.

Следует понимать, что для сервера нет никакой разницы между живым пользователем и роботом. И в смысле защиты чего бы то ни было никакой разницы между ними нет. Если пользователь без пароля может войти в админку, то и робот может. Если пользователь не может - то и робот не войдет.

Если только умудриться добавить код счетчика - метрики или GA в админку, то они, разумеется, могут собирать некоторую информацию о закрытых страницах, если их не закрыть через роботс. но правильнее будет просто не добавлять никакие коды счетчиков в админку вообще.

Comment: Авторизация есть. А роботы не смогут как-нибудь сохранить данную страничку авторизированного админа?

Comment: @gilo1212 Страницу авторизованного админа никак не смогут сохранить. Только смогут страницу не авторизованного админа, если в robots.txt не закрыть.

Comment: @Ипатьев А скажите пожалуйста, те страницы которые доступны по авторизации другим пользователям, роботы тоже не смогут посмотреть и сохранить?

Comment: @Ипатьев а что это за коды счетчиков?

Comment: @Ипатьев Не ответите что за счетчики?

Comment: @gilo1212 боты (обычные, поисковые) не проходят авторизацию, а просто делают get-запросы без передачи кук. Т.е. никакие страницы где нужна авторизация они не смогут индексировать.

Comment: @Ипатьев Большое спасибо. Успехов вам.

Comment: @gilo1212 если это не сарказм, то спасибо не мне. А какие именно счетчики, написано в прямо в теле поста: метрика и GA.